# Best practices for rotating large datasets?

Tags: design, database, web-applications, sql

[edit]Turns out there's 1.5 million records... The SQL database is taking about 17-20 seconds to run the query. Would it be best to have Java handle the joins and rearranging in that case? Since this is a web app, if multiple users are getting Excel exports, would the long queries reduce the overall performance of the site?[/edit]

I have a dataset that contains roughly 70,000 records. For simplicity's sake, let's say the data currently looks like this:

User ID | Question | Answer

In our web application, the data needs to be rotated 90 degrees and exported into Excel, such that we have the following:

User ID | Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3 ....

I think we end up with around 50 or so columns.

Should the data be rearranged on the database side using pivot tables or should it be rearranged on the application side?
Which solution would be the easiest to maintain?
Which solution would have the greatest performance?

Comment: (Not completely sure, so not answer) - The database server is likely beefier than the excel app... don't confuse excel more than needs be done.  Rotate on the server.  See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175574 for how to do it in Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: It should only take you about 10 minutes to knock up a prototype on each side, and find out which one performs better.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I wish... The problem we have is that the values for the columns are unknown as the questions are created by the end users. I'm going to give this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100634/mysql-pivot-table-or-something) a shot and test it against writing a java app to do it... It's just that the project lead on our project won't let us use stored procedures. :(

Comment: So performance might not be your only consideration then... Excel spreadsheets can easily handle 70,000 rows nowadays.  If you can't pivot on the sql database server, I wouldn't bother trying to do it server-side.

Comment: These days, 70k rows isn't really "large" anymore, nor is the 1400 rows your pivoted results would be.  If your database has a pivot feature, doing it server-side is a no-brainer.  Even if the DB does not, if you're going to use the data more than once or twice, it'd probably make sense to write it up server-side.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll report my findings soon. I was a bit worried because with the regular query, the project lead's code takes over 5 minutes to run... but I think it's poorly implemented code. (I'll never understand why they outsourced the project lead position, but that's another story)

Comment: Opposed to MichaelT: knowing Excel and some SQL databases, I am pretty sure the most databases (including Oracle and MS SQL) are far from beeing "beefier" than Excel for such things.

Comment: Just for clarification, when I mean the application side, I meant the middle tier. i.e. grab the data from SQL and re-arrange it using Java. I was able to run the query and it was much quicker, but due to maximum string limitations on the database setup, the solution for this project will have to be a hybrid Java-SQL solution since the Group_concat function hit the limit. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: @DocBrown for clarification, I do know excel and sql quite well... its just I don't have the resources (a windows machine) to be able to do the research necessary to write a good answer about how to do things.  The other bit is that Excel versions have differnt limits - Excel 2003 was limited to 64k rows x 256 col.  2010 is limited to 1M rows x 16k col. This may impact working with 70k of something no matter what the database does... and I can't verify it anymore.

Comment: @MichaelT: yes, that's true, and when I wrote the comment, the new information about the 1,5 million records was not there. And I missed that this is a web app - so the export in Excel format has to be done without Excel itself (which would not suitable for a server application).

Comment: @user2708395: You are not going to export the 1,5 mio records into *one* excel file, I guess? And you are talking of some "joins in Java"? There is obviously some missing information about what is really going on, so come on, give a better description of the problem or expect not to get any good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are exporting data, in this situation I'd typically build the export file manually in code.  Pull back the rows sorted by user id, and loop through them.  While the dataset would be large, the query itself would be very simple and shouldnt stress the database much.  No need to otherwise burden the sql server with keeping the 'compiled' data set maintained when its not needed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Usually app tiers are easier to scale horizontally than databases. So when possible, doing more on the app tier (or client), and less on the DB allows you to throw hardware at the problem if 100 users decide to run their 20 second query at once.

If you don't care about scalability, then I'd look at the explain plan for the query first, and what causes it to be slow. It might be possible to make it faster server side.